# Recovery email still includes instructions for signing on using an OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, email, account-recovery

The mail sent [when trying to recover a password](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) tells me I can log in to Stack Overflow through Wordpress with the help of an OpenId.

> - Click the "more login options" link, enter "[my openID url]" in the OpenID field and click "Submit"

However, this option does not exist anymore; it's also the reason why I requested a new password!

#### Recommended solution

Just need to remove the paragraph about the log in by an OpenId in the recovery mail.

Comment: TL;DR: you're in the right place. Just start a new question and report the bug. :)

Comment: Kind of a shorter route to that whole thing, eh @ShadowWizard?

Comment: @Shog9 I prefered to try and teach the OP how to fish, not do it for them. But yeah, no doubt doing it ourselves is 1) Faster 2) Usually better. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This should have been fixed through some related work that was done in the past few months (and due to that, we can not reliably repro this right now, but are confident that it is fixed). Please let us know if it is still happening.